# Android studio1.0 Cannot launch SDK manager

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

getting error when iam trying to launch sdk manager in new android studio 1.0,even i have set environment variables correctly,and made changes in android.bat,but getting error like this:

```
 Cannot launch SDK manager.
 Output:

 '-v' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 Invalid path
 ERROR: SWT folder '' does not exist.
 Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.
```

this is my android.bat

```
  @echo off
 rem Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
  rem
 rem Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
rem you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
rem You may obtain a copy of the License at
  rem
  rem      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 rem
  rem Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  rem distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  rem WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  rem See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  rem limitations under the License.

  rem Useful links:
  rem Command-line reference:
  rem   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

  rem don't modify the caller's environment
  setlocal enableextensions

    rem Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
    rem and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
  set prog=%~f0

   rem Grab current directory before we change it
   set work_dir=%cd%

    rem Change current directory and drive to where the script is, to avoid
    rem issues with directories containing whitespaces.
  cd /d %~dp0


  rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
   set java_exe=
    call lib\find_java.bat
 if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
  set java_exe=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe

   set jar_path=lib\sdkmanager.jar;lib\swtmenubar.jar

  rem Set SWT.Jar path based on current architecture (x86 or x86_64)
  set swt_path=lib\x86
 :MkTempCopy
rem Copy android.bat and its required libs to a temp dir.
rem This avoids locking the tool dir in case the user is trying to update it.

set tmp_dir=%TEMP%\temp-android-tool
xcopy %swt_path% %tmp_dir%\%swt_path% /I /E /C /G /R /Y /Q > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\common.jar         %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-codec*     %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-compress*  %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\commons-logging*   %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\dvlib.jar          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\guava*             %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\httpclient*        %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\httpcore*          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\httpmime*          %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\layoutlib-api.jar  %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\org-eclipse-*      %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\sdk*               %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul
copy /B /D /Y lib\swtmenubar.jar     %tmp_dir%\lib\        > nul

rem jar_path and swt_path are relative to PWD so we don't need to adjust them, just change dirs.
set tools_dir=%cd%
cd /d %tmp_dir%

:EndTempCopy

rem The global ANDROID_SWT always override the SWT.Jar path
if defined ANDROID_SWT set swt_path=%ANDROID_SWT%

if exist "%swt_path%" goto SetPath
echo ERROR: SWT folder '%swt_path%' does not exist.
echo Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your          platform.
goto :EOF

:SetPath
 rem Finally exec the java program and end here.
REM set REMOTE_DEBUG=-Xdebug    -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
  call "%java_exe% %REMOTE_DEBUG%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir=%tools_dir%" "-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.workdir=%work_dir%" -classpath "%jar_path%;%swt_path%\swt.jar" com.android.sdkmanager.Main %*
```

rem EOF

Answer (score 0):

It's better to install 32 bit JDK for the system and then install the Android SDK tools

But make sure to set correctly the java path and classpath in the environment variables.

For example

```
JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
```

Then add this line

```
set java_exe=C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

After these lines in my android.bat :

```
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=
call lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
```

android.bat is in `/sdk_folder/tools`

Also you can delete this line

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%java_exe%" -jar lib\archquery.jar') do set swt_path=lib\%%a
```

and replace it with

```
set swt_path=lib\x86
```

For 32 bit systems

Comment: yeah i have already set that correctly,using jdk7 on windows xp 32bit operating system.

Comment: Sorry not getting you point.And i have mentioned here iam using new android studio.

Comment: Try to change android.bat which is in `/sdk_folder_tools` and change it as i said

Comment: So what is your problem now ? try to add sdk again.for example change it to another folder and add agian

Comment: Now nothing is happening when i click on that sdk manger icon even that error.